# Не могу понять смысл ошибки

Tags: android, aide

Кто подскажет, что означает данное исключение:
"Packaging error
java.lang.RuntimeException:xn
unknown tag byte:12"?

Answer (score 0):

ЭТО происходит из-за какой-то библиотеки, если вы реализуете в своем проекте при использовании Aide.

У Aide проблемы с большинством библиотек.

Попробуйте вместо этого использовать другой редактор кода или другую библиотеку.

Теперь я знаю, где на самом деле ошибка.

Если то же самое произойдет с вами, обратите внимание, что это связано с сторонней библиотекой, которую вы используете в своем проекте.

Таким образом, решение состоит в том, чтобы удалить эту библиотеку из вашего проекта и попробовать другую, более того, попробуйте написать код с нуля для этой задачи, если это возможно, вместо использования таких библиотек.

Это происходит потому, что эти библиотеки используют другую библиотеку или библиотеки.

Надеюсь, это поможет тебе.

Удачного кодирования :)

Comment: У android.support.v7 вроде не было никогда проблем